# Intermittent "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream." - Mongo C#

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-.net-driver, system.net

Since switching to Mongo SSL connection, using the C# Driver (v1.11.0), we have been getting intermittent errors in production with this error message:

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Our connection string is in this format:

```
mongodb://user:pass@host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3/dbname?ssl=true&authsource=admin&sslVerifyCertificate=true&replicaSet=replicaSetName
```

The DB is hosted in MongoDB ATLAS offering, not sure if that will make any difference.

The stack trace prior to our own classes is:

> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open()
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(BsonBuffer buffer, Int32 requestId)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage message)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.Execute(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)

We have upgraded to .NET 4.61 and placed the following line in our global asax application start:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

At a loss at what else to look at, and its hard to troubleshoot as we're unable to debug locally...  any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can we see the full exception?  Also, the driver does not use ServicePointManager.  MongoClientSettings has SSL related settings in it where you can specify the protocols.  How intermittent?

Comment: I have to set the exception to log remotely, as its too intermittent to occur locally.  Currently I log the Message and the stack trace, which other bit would you like to see?

Comment: This occurs every couple of hours on a live site, which has hits every couple of minutes

Comment: The ServicePointManager line was just a trial as I saw that on another post.  I was getting the error prior to this line being introduced

Comment: I understand. But you can set the protocols like you are doing in ServicePointManager on the ssl settings in MongoClientSettings. Worth trying...

Comment: Without seeing an error or stacktrace, this is shooting in the dark and we won't know what else to ask for until we see them...

Comment: Good idea, I'll look into that this morning. Er

Comment: So turned out the issue was due to there being an overload of connections open on the instance, as one of our jobs was opening a new connection every few seconds and not closing them.  Correcting this behaviour meant the instance could respond.  Still a very odd error message to receive...